# `std::move_as_tuple` and `std::when_all`

Tags: c++, promise, template-meta-programming, c++17

Working with futures and `.then`, I keep running into the problem of needing to "capture by move" in a lambda. In fact, not only that, but when implementing e.g. `when_all`, I find myself needing to capture a whole parameter-pack. Neither of these things are supported out of the box in C++17.

However, we *can* capture a whole parameter pack "by forward", using `std::forward_as_tuple` and `std::apply`. So I decided to write a `std::move_as_tuple` that would do the same thing as `forward_as_tuple` but for moving instead of forwarding.

How does this code look? And is there a simpler way to accomplish my goal?

```
template<class... Types>
constexpr auto move_as_tuple(Types&&... args)
{
    return std::forward_as_tuple(std::move(args)...);
}
```

Sample usage (which is also fair game for critique):

```
future<std::tuple<>> when_all()
{
    promise<std::tuple<>> p;
    p.set_value({});
    return p.get_future();
}

template<class F, class... Rest>
future<std::tuple<F, Rest...>> when_all(F f, Rest... rest)
{
    return f.then([rest = move_as_tuple(rest...)](auto f) {
        auto w = [](auto&&... as) { return when_all(std::forward<decltype(as)>(as)...); };
        return std::apply(w, rest).then([f = std::move(f)](auto future_of_tuple_of_rest) {
            return std::tuple_cat(std::make_tuple(std::move(f)), future_of_tuple_of_rest.get());
        }).get();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Self-answering for posterity.)

There's a major flaw in my above implementation of `when_all`: It calls `.get()`! This can cause the thread to block indefinitely. We need to eliminate that `.get` somehow, or at least make sure that we only ever call `.get` on a future that has just been passed in as the argument of a `.then` callback.

The reason I was calling `.get` was to work around a type incompatibility: the type of

```
auto SUBEXPRESSION =
    std::apply(w, rest).then([f = std::move(f)](auto future_of_tuple_of_rest) {
        return std::tuple_cat(std::make_tuple(std::move(f)), future_of_tuple_of_rest.get());
    })
```

is `std::future<std::tuple<F, Rest...>>`, which means that the type of

```
auto EXPRESSION =
    f.then([...](auto f) {
        return SUBEXPRESSION;
    });
});
```

is `std::future<decltype(SUBEXPRESSION)>`, which is to say `std::future<std::future<std::tuple<F, Rest...>>>`. That's too many futures! So I was trying to work around this by calling `.get` right before returning the "inner" future.

Turns out that `boost::future` and `std::experimental::future` (in the Concurrency TS) already have a solution for this problem. It's called `.unwrap`, and the idea is that if `decltype(f)` is `future<future<T>>`, then `decltype(f.unwrap())` is `future<T>`.

In Boost's case, this is currently provided as a constructor `explicit future(future<future>&&)` instead of as an `.unwrap` member function, but there's a bug open to provide `.unwrap` directly.

In the Concurrency TS, `.then` also implicitly calls `.unwrap` on the callback's return value if that return value is seen to be of type `future<future<T>>`.

So my solution was simply to add a call to `.unwrap` (well, the Boost explicit constructor), and then everything was happy.

---

There's another showstopping problem with the above code: it doesn't compile for more than one argument, because I'm missing the `mutable` keyword on both of the lambdas involved. You can't "move out of" the captured `f` unless `f` is non-const, which means you need `mutable` on the inner lambda; and at least GCC is unhappy with `std::apply(w, rest)` unless `rest` is non-const, which means you need `mutable` on the outer lambda too.

---

Finally, I decided to stop trying to capture references to things, and just replaced everything with capture-by-value. This simplified the code to the point where I didn't see any reason to keep `move_as_tuple` as its own function at all.

My final code:

```
auto when_all() {
    promise<tuple<>> p;
    p.set_value({});
    return p.get_future();
}

template<class F, class... Rest>
auto when_all(F f, Rest... rest) {
    return future<tuple<F, Rest...>>(
        f.then([rest = make_tuple(std::move(rest)...)](auto f) mutable {
            auto w = [](auto... as) { return when_all(std::move(as)...); };
            return apply(w, std::move(rest)).then(
                [f = std::move(f)](auto future_of_tuple_of_rest) mutable {
                    return tuple_cat(make_tuple(std::move(f)), future_of_tuple_of_rest.get());
                }
            );
        })
    );
}
```